# for loop efficiency in R: lm and nls

Tags: r

I am running some simulations in R and for this I am using a for loop.

My code is as follows:

```
clupeaformis_aligned<-read.FASTA("Coregonus clupeaformis_aligned.fas")
clupeaformis_haplo<-haplotype(clupeaformis_aligned)

set.seed(1)
iter <- 1000

clupeaformis_invest <- rep(NA,  iter)

ptm <- proc.time()

for(i in 1:iter){

clupeaformis_haplo_rand <- haploAccum(clupeaformis_aligned, method="random", permutations=1000) 

N <- clupeaformis_haplo_rand$sequences
H <- clupeaformis_haplo_rand$n.haplotypes

d <- data.frame(N, H)

clupeaformis_lm <- lm(log(H) ~ log(N), data = d)

clupeaformis_nls <- nls(H ~ a*N^b, start=list(a=exp(coef(clupeaformis_lm)[1]), b=coef(clupeaformis_lm)[2]), data = d)

clupeaformis_invest[i] <- invest(clupeaformis_nls, y0 = 21, interval = "inversion", upper = 1000000)

}
proc.time() - ptm.
```

With 1000 iterations, the loop takes ~ 7 minutes to run, but with 10,000 iterations, it takes ~70 minutes! I believe nls may be the culprit, as it is an expensive function to iterate over.

I am thinking of using alternatives like lapply, but I imagine it's no more efficient than a for loop. Is there an even better alternative that takes a fraction of the time for a large number of iterations?

Any advice is welcomed.

Comment: The method in which you loop isn't the issue.  You could do some parallel computing to speed it up but the real issue is that each iteration takes a non-trivial amount of time.

Comment: Profile your code or simply wrap with `system.time()` to determine where the bottleneck lies, then optimize. Here are some profiling resources:  https://www.r-bloggers.com/profiling-r-code/, http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html. If `nls` is the culprit but you need to fit your models using `nls`, then the best you can do is parallelize across cores with doSNOW on Windows or doMC on Mac.

Comment: You are correct that switching from `for` to `lapply` will make a negligible difference in time - what takes time isn't looping, it's what you do inside the loop. If you have multiple cores available you could parallelize the loop, which will give you a speed up of (almost) as many cores as you use, but simplifying what is int the loop is the best way to reduce time.

Comment: You can shave a little but off by calling `lm.fit` directly rather than `lm`, but you're probably right that most of the time is `nls`. Profile your code as suggested to make sure that's the case, and I'd experiment with different `nls.control` options to try to make that bit go faster.

Comment: Thank you all for these great comments. Running in parallel with doParallel is faster, but ultimately still slow... Taking ~35 min for 10,000 iterations.